# Avoid page break after \item-followed-by-newline

Tags: lists, page-breaking

My document has multiple occurrences of the code fragment

```
\item~\newline
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{...}
\end{center}
\item
```

and occasionally, the first `item` comes right at the end of a page, so the item label is separated from the figure. How can I avoid this? (I use this construct so as to get the item label *above* the figure instead of aligned with the figure's bottom, which is what happens by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
 \newcommand\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some text. \par
\vspace{0.95\textheight}
\begin{itemize}
  \item~\mynobreakpar
    \begin{center} Here is an item \\line 2\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

(Instead of center you can then also use \centering).

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention "occasionally", you could just use `\needspace{2\baselineskip}`<sup>*</sup> before the item to require at least two `\baselineskip` space; if not, issue a `\break`. This is provided by the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace
\begin{document}
Here is some text. \par
\vspace{​0.88\textheight}
\begin{itemize}
  \item~\newline
    Here is an item
  \needspace{2\baselineskip}% Remove to see the effect
  \item~\newline
    Here is an item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

<sup>*</sup> Technically, it might be more appropriate to use `\needspace{\dimexpr\topsep+\baselineskip}` for top-of-list items and `\needspace{\dimexpr\itemsep+\baselineskip}` for non-top items, for obvious reasons.

Comment: That works great for the one-offs (like fixing up the document at the very end). But is there an approach that will avoid the problem altogether?

Comment: You can patch `\item` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox). Add `\usepackage{etoolbox} \preto\item{\needspace{2\baselineskip}}` in your document preamble. Would that work? That would be general though for all lists (`enumerate`, `itemize` and `description`).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a page break at the line break with `\nopagebreak`. But there's also a problem in that `center` has an implicit page break. I'll probably burn in hell for using `\centerline`, but...

```
\item~\nopagebreak\\[-\baselineskip]
    \centerline{\includegraphics{...}}
```

Comment: Why `\centerline` and not `{\centering ... }`?

Comment: I tried `{\centering\includegraphics{...}\par}`, but that also centered the bullet. To fix that, you'd need to change the first line to `\item\nopagebreak\\[-\baselineskip]\par`.