# Avoid page break between enumerate label and first line of item

Tags: page-breaking, enumerate, labels, mdframed

I've defined a shortcut to create boxed questions like this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }
\newcommand{\restorequestionlabel}{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }}
\newenvironment{questions}
    {\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label=\textbf{\questionlabel\arabic*.}, wide]}
    {\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\itembr}{\item\mbox{}}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\itembr\begin{mdframed}#1\end{mdframed}}
```

When used like this usually produces what I want:

```
\begin{questions}

\question{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?}
consectetur adipiscing elit

\question{sed do eiusmod tempor}
 incididunt ut labore et dolore

\end{questions}
```

[image: Questions displaying properly]

Unfortunately, sometimes the page break occurs between the label **Question ?.** and the top of the box. I'm using `mdframed` and I do want the boxes to split across the pages, but not before the first line.

I've tried putting `\nopagebreak` in different places but it didn't work. I've seen other posts suggesting to use `minipage` but is not ideal since it wouldn't allow page breaks at any other line.

Comment: Maybe see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2644

Comment: @user94293 That question is about a page break befoe the start of the environment and not between label and item contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38444/103046) and used the package `needspace` to require a certain amount of space without a pagebreak in each of your `question` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }
\newcommand{\restorequestionlabel}{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }}
\newenvironment{questions}
    {\begin{enumerate}[align=left,label=\textbf{\questionlabel\arabic*.}, wide]}
    {\end{enumerate}}
\newcommand{\itembr}{\needspace{6\baselineskip}\item\mbox{}}
\newcommand{\question}[1]{\itembr\begin{mdframed}#1\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{questions}
\question{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?}
consectetur adipiscing elit
\question{sed do eiusmod tempor}
 incididunt ut labore et dolore
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

To use `6\baselineskip` was just by try-and-error, there might be a better way of getting the needed size.